# how to get back a void license afterif we root or flash rom a device

Tags: stock-rom

does stock roming my phone recover its official update license?? if yes how to stock rom? if not is there another way to recover the license back?? I want to stoke romroomm it to an official kitkat version and software update it to lollipop by going to settings>my phone>about device>update.. is this possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does , just go to [Download stock rom file](http://forum.xda-developers.com/all)

Since you didn't specified your cell phone model,  just go to xda forum search for your cell phone model and there you will find stock rom file and procedure to install it , you can unroot at any time and you will be able to update your phone ,provided by manufacture. 
If you still having problem just provide your phone model for more exact link